# Gradle tasks do not set Standard Input in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, gradle

I have a project that uses the Leap Motion SDK which I managed to get running on both Windows and Linux. I'm having trouble reading with reading input when running from IntelliJ however.

My main sets up a controller and listener which dumps data to the console in another thread then the main thread blocks until a line is read then exits.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val listener = new SampleListener
  val controller = new Controller

  controller.addListener(listener)

  var input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine()

  while (true) Thread sleep (1000)

  controller.removeListener(listener)
}
```

In IntelliJ it seems the standard input stream is not set, so the readLine return immediately and the program exits. I've had to put in an infinite loop of sleeps to keep keep it running whilst in the IDE. Further, stopping the gradle task from IntelliJ doesn't actually kill the java app.

I read that adding the standardInput line following my [buildscript](http://pastebin.com/X8KMBncc) will make sure the standard input is not null but it still doesn't work in IntelliJ:

```
run {
    main = 'uk.co.abp24.Launch'
    standardInput = System.in
    jvmArgs = [ "-Djava.library.path=lib"]
}
```

If you know how to solve either of these problems please let me know, thank you.

Comment: How exactly do you run the app from within IntelliJ? Is Gradle even involved here?

Comment: Just running as normal or clicking the gradle run task. The buildscript is linked in the post.

Comment: I can confirm this issue, I can't seem to be able to solve it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267508/wait-for-user-input-while-debugging-on-intellij-idea-and-gradle), do you have any updates on this?

Comment: My guess is you are running in debug mode yes?  The standard input line was working for me and then I flipped to debug and *poof* out went the magic smoke.  I'm thinking debug doesn't execute "run" the same way...but I'm not a Gradle expert so I don't know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for user input while debugging on IntelliJ IDEA and Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267508/wait-for-user-input-while-debugging-on-intellij-idea-and-gradle)