# Wait for user input while debugging on IntelliJ IDEA and Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have the simplest Java application that just works if executed from command line. But if I want to debug it through IntelliJ IDEA 14 Ultimate, the `System.in.read()` part always returns `-1`, without ever typing anything into it:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("This is a test... Hit [enter] to exit.");
        int cha = System.in.read();
        System.out.println("You hit [enter], exiting...");
    }
}
```

Is this some kind of issue with Windows 8.1 or is it IntelliJ IDEA related?

**UPDATE**: I have found out the issue presents itself only when starting the application through Gradle (*gradlew run*), so it's a Gradle issue. This is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'
mainClassName = 'net.frakbot.ws.Main'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

run {
    main = 'net.frakbot.ws.Main'
    standardInput = System.in
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Comment: Are you using Gradle deamon? In that case you can't read from stdin.

Comment: Actually, you can read from standard input (see http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:standardInput), and in fact running `gradlew run` from the terminal works. It just doesn't in IntelliJ IDEA's integrated Debug/Run console.

Comment: Ok cool, nice to know that bug has been fixed :-)

Comment: No, it hasn't been fixed :D I still would like to debug starting Gradle from IDEA.

Answer (score 2):

It <s>is</s> has been a known bug in Intellij Idea: [bug description](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-133811#tab=Linked%20Issues)

EDIT: Apparently, as pointed out in the comments, it has been fixed since this answer was given and patched Intellij will be released in Summer 2017.

Comment: Just ran into this today... Looks like it's been a known issue for 2+ years at this point.  Any way to find out if there will actually be any progress?

Comment: No idea other than monitoring the bug status and waiting for the fix, I think.

Comment: This issue is already fixed for IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2. EAP is available [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/).

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine on my windows 7 machine with IntelliJ IDEA 14 community edition.

Comment: No I haven't tested with gradle. I simply executed code snipped you have provided.

Comment: Turns out the issue is with the Gradle "application" plugin.