# Gradle run task accepts input when run in console, but not as an IDEA run configuration

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have the following Java main class which I am trying to compile and run using the Gradle plugin in IntelliJ IDEA:

```
package com.mikidep.bookshop;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Inserisci testo qui: ");
        System.out.println(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Yee!");
    }
}
```

My build.gradle follows:

```
group 'com.mikidep.bookshop'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "com.mikidep.bookshop.Main"

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

run {
    standardInput = System.in
}
```

Now if I run `gradle run -q` in a terminal everything works as expected. However there is this IDEA run configuration that I would like to use to test-run:

[image: IDEA Run configuration]

Everything is fine until I do some console input. `in.nextLine()` throws the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line
>   found     at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)    at
>   com.mikidep.bookshop.Main.main(Main.java:10)

I also tried to debug it and noticed that all fields in `System.in` seem zeroed out, like the whole stream hadn't been initialized. Anyone knows what's happening?

**EDIT:** I just verified that this affects the build script as well: I added this lines to the run task

```
System.out.println("Wait...")
System.in.read()
System.out.println("Ok!")
```

But Gradle prints those two lines right away, without waiting for my input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for user input while debugging on IntelliJ IDEA and Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267508/wait-for-user-input-while-debugging-on-intellij-idea-and-gradle)

Answer (score 2):

`System.in` is not the Script parameters.

In command line, since you don't specify any parameters that Gradle expects, it just uses the remaining of what you typed as standard input. In IDEA the standard input and the script parameters are separated and the standard input comes from the run or debug console window.

Comment: I know, `-q` is just to prevent gradle output from cluttering the console. When I run it into some terminal I input some well recognizable text, which is thrown back like I expect the program to. If I run it in IDEA the program doesn't even wait for input, it just throws the exception and terminates.

Comment: It should wait for input, so I'd say it's a bug in IDEA.

Comment: Also I added some info in the question.